# Underlie, Underlay, Underlying and Underlaying

Tags: meaning, synonyms

What is the difference between "*underlay*", "*underlie*" and their present continuous forms (and adjectives) "*underlying*" and "*underlaying*"?

And what is the right word to say something like:

> The actual behavior of something depends on the underlying platform.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I understand it:

[***Underlie***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underlie) means to lie under or to serve as a basis for something else.

> There are many fundamental problems which underlie our failed relationship

*Underlying* refers to that which underlies, in this case the problems.

---

[***Underlay***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underlay) means to place something under something else or to provide something as support for something else; it can be contrasted with *overlay*. It may also be the past tense form of *underlie*.

> The sound engineer decided to underlay the main track with some special effects

*Underlaying* refers to that which underlays, in this case the sound engineer.

---

So I hope this makes it clear that in your example sentence *underlying* is the correct word. The platforms lie under (and do not lay something else under) the actual behavior of something.

Comment: It's the same situation as [_lie_ and _lay_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/3kindsofword.jpg). Like _lie, underlie_ is intransitive; like _lay, underlay_ is transitive.

Comment: @JohnLawler Hmmm, I don't think that's true. [Some sources](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/underlie) list *underlie* as transitive. The object of *underlie* is what the subject lies under, as in my example sentence, if you reduce it to: "*Many problems underlie our failed relationship*".

Comment: Is _our failed relationship_ a direct object, then? How about DO tests? Not every NP that follows a verb is a DO; for instance, _He weighs 100 kg_ is an intransitive sentence, because _100 kg_ is a measure phrase, not a DO.

Comment: @JohnLawler Isn't it? What else would *our failed relationship* be in this context? And what DO test are you referring to?

Comment: There are a number. Passivization, Extraction, and Insertion, for instance. Respectively, _??Our relationship is underlain by many problems, ?*It's our relationship that many problems underlie, ??Many problems underlie deeply our relationship_. Fairly ambivalent results there; the first two should be good and the last bad for a normal DO. I suspect what we have here is some variation in transitivity. Not surprising, given the widespread variation between _lie_ and _lay_, and the fact that _underlie_ and _underlay_ are both rare and technical.